# Result about Matrices of form $B(AB)^{-1}A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am trying to prove the following result. So far my only idea was to try using the [formula for inversion of block matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion), but that did not get me very far. Any help will be much appreciated.

---

**Setup**

Suppose $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are $n \times m$ and $m \times n$ matrices respectively, with $n<m$ and

$$\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{A})=\operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{B})=n.$$

For some $p \lt m$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ be an $m \times m$ diagonal matrix with

$$\mathbf{\Gamma}_{i,i}=1, \; \text{ if} \;\; i \le p, \;\;\;\;\; \text{ and } \;\;\;\;\;  \mathbf{\Gamma}_{i,i}=\gamma, \; \text{ if }\;\; i \gt p.$$

Consider the matrices $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{N}$ given by

$$\mathbf{M} = \; \mathbf{B}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A}, \;\;\;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\;\;\;
\mathbf{N} = \; \mathbf{\Gamma B}(\mathbf{A \Gamma}^2 \mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{A \Gamma}. $$

Finally, for any matrix $\mathbf{M}$, let $\mathbf{M_{p}}$ be the matrix made up of only the  the first $p$ rows and $p$ columns of $\mathbf{M}$.

---

**Conjecture**

> $$ \mathbf{M_{p}}(\mathbf{I_{p}}-\mathbf{N_{p}})= \gamma^2 (\mathbf{I_{p}}-\mathbf{M_{p}})\mathbf{N_{p}} $$

where $\mathbf{I_{p}}$ stands for the identity matrix of size $p$.

---

**Matlab Code**

Here is a simple Matlab code that allows you to test the conjecture for random matrices:

```
n = 3; 
m = 7; 
p = 4;     

lb = -1;
ub = 1;

A = unifrnd(lb,ub,n,m);
B = unifrnd(lb,ub,m,n);
g = unifrnd(lb,ub,1,1);
G = eye(m).*[ones(p,m);ones(m-p,p),ones(m-p,m-p)*g];


M = (B/(A*B))*A;
N = (G*B/(A*G*G*B))*A*G;

disp(M(1:p,1:p)*(eye(p)-N(1:p,1:p))./(g^2*(eye(p)-M(1:p,1:p))*N(1:p,1:p)))
```

It should return a $p \times p$ matrix with only ones to verify the conjecture.

Comment: So, have you run your script? What's the result?

Comment: @user1551 I have and for all combinations of $n$, $m$, and $p$ that I've tried I get the desired result. Notice also, that the code sets up matrices with random numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is any elegant solution, but your conjecture can be easily proved by a continuity argument. Let $A=\pmatrix{X&Y}$ and $B=\pmatrix{Z\\ W}$, where $X$ and $Z$ are $n\times n$. Suppose that $X$ and $Z$ are invertible. Then the followings are equivalent: (for convenience, I write $g$ instead of $\gamma$)
\begin{align}
M_p(I_p-N_p)&=g^2(I_p-M_p)N_p,\tag{1}\\
Z(XZ+YW)^{-1}X [ I - Z(XZ+g^2YW)^{-1}X ] &= g^2 [ I - Z(XZ+YW)^{-1}X ] Z(XZ+g^2YW)^{-1}X,\\
(XZ+YW)^{-1}X [ I - Z(XZ+g^2YW)^{-1}X ] &= g^2 [ I - (XZ+YW)^{-1}XZ ] (XZ+g^2YW)^{-1}X,\\
(XZ+YW)^{-1} [ I - XZ(XZ+g^2YW)^{-1} ] &= g^2 [ I - (XZ+YW)^{-1}XZ ] (XZ+g^2YW)^{-1},\\
[ I - XZ(XZ+g^2YW)^{-1} ] &= g^2 YW (XZ+g^2YW)^{-1},\\
[ (XZ+g^2YW) - XZ ] &= g^2 YW,\\
g^2YW&=g^2YW.
\end{align}
Hence $(1)$ is also true for general $X,Z$.